# Using Preg Match to line break full row of text by timestamp

Tags: php, api, soap-client, preg-split

I'm not sure how to explain this but I'll try my best. I have a full line of text that I'm reading from an API using SoapClient with PHP. When I'm getting the data it's putting all of the data on one line. I want to be able to filter through the data and throw it into an array using preg_match but I'm not too sure what pattern I would use to do it. The example is from a chat session and each new line I want to be starting with the timestamp. So for example:

> 8:02AM Charlie connects to chat client 8:04AM Agent Jackie says "Hi
>   Charlie, how can I help you today" 8:06AM Charlie say[s, "I'm looking
>   to get an account balance."

The above is an example of how the one line of text is sent back to me. However, I want to be able to break it up by time stamp and be in an array like below:

```
array(
    [0] => "8:02AM Charlie connects to chat client",
    [1] => "8:04am Agent Jackie says 'Hi Charlie, how can I help you today'",
    [2] => "8:06AM Charlie says, 'I'm looking to get an account balance.'"
)
```

I've been looking on google and here but I can't seem to find the proper wording to look for what I need.

This is the data that is returned from the SoapClient:

```
stdClass Object (
 [getChatResult] => getChat_OK
 [sChatLog] => 8:02AM Charlie connects to chat client 8:04AM Agent Jackie says "Hi Charlie, how can I help you today" 8:06AM Charlie says, "I'm looking to get an account balance."
 )
```

Comment: are you sure each line isn't sperated by new lines or some other non printable character?

Comment: I've edited the top post to reflect exactly what the data looks like when it is retrieved using soapclient.

Comment: @Shane, if there is a non-printable character, check the source of the page and you can see if the lines automatically break (`"\n"`) or if there is tabs between them (`"\t"`)

Comment: I'm so silly, tks Tim and Hamish, I took a look and I just added <PRE></PRE> and echo'd the data in between the <PRE> tags and it puts it exactly as it should.

Comment: awesome - so `explode("\n", chatLog)` should do the trick

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[preg_split](http://nl2.php.net/preg_split) with a positive lookahead (`(?=...)`).

```
preg_split('/(?=[12]?[0-9]:[0-9]{2}[ap]m)/i',$string,0,PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

Comment: I don't understand the positive lookahead. If your entire regex is the the lookahead, isn't that redundant?

Comment: @Walkerneo: that is to get the timestamp in the array of strings. If you remove the lookahead, the splitting will still happen, but the resulting array would have the time-stamp (the string to split on) removed from the strings. If we go the `PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE` route, we would manually have to prepend that delimiter to the strings again. By saying: _'split on any **zero-width** place which is followed by a timestamp'_, nothing is removed from the string, and the result is exactly as the OP desired without further processing.

Answer (score 0):

```
$s='8:02AM Charlie connects to chat client 8:04AM Agent Jackie says "Hi Charlie, how can I help you today" 8:06AM Charlie says, "I\'m looking to get an account balance."';

// Split the string
$pattern='/\d{1,2}\:\d\d[AaPp][Mm]\s/';
$split=preg_split($pattern, $s, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE | PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);

//Combine time and content
$final=array();
for ($i=0;$i<sizeof($split);) $final[]=$split[$i++].$split[$i++];

print_r($final);
```